# Kotlin - How to eliminate decimals except the first two

Tags: kotlin, math, decimal

What I want to achieve is to keep 2 decimals and eliminate any extra decimals without any rounding for example

3.556664 to 3.55 (NOT ROUNDING)

I Tried the following

```kotlin
    "%.2f".format(3.556).toFloat() // the result is 3.56
    DecimalFormat("#.##").format(3.556).toFloat() // the result is 3.56
    BigDecimal(3.556).setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN).toFloat() // the result is 3.56
```

Comment: The question says ‘without rounding’ — but truncating _is_ a form of [rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding); specifically, it's rounding down. (Technically, that could be rounding towards 0, or rounding towards -∞.) I think you mean that you don't want rounding to the _nearest_ 0.01 (which also has several variations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val x = Math.floor(3.556 * 100) / 100 // == 3.55
```

> Math.floor returns value that less than or equal to the argument and
> is equal to a mathematical integer.

In our case 3.556 * 100 = 355.6 and the floor would be 355.0, hence 355/100 = 3.55

Comment: it's working bur, can you add an explanation, please ?

Comment: Math.floor returns value that less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer. In our case 3.556 * 100 = 355.6 and the floor would be 355.0 =>  355/100 = 3.55

Comment: That's a good mathematics trick

Answer (score 3):

You can set a rounding mode on the DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat("#.##")
    .apply { roundingMode = RoundingMode.FLOOR }
    .format(3.556)
```

However, note that a Float does not actually store the number in decimal (base 10), and so it is not a suitable format for a number that you need to have a specific number of decimal places. When you convert it to a String, you may find that the number of decimal places has changed. To ensure a specific number of decimal places, you need BigDecimal.

Comment: I have math result `3.5566` in float and i want to keep only the first 2 decimal to represent it as string, what the suitable way to do that

Comment: This code would be fine because it’s not converting it back into a Float. The other answer is a Float so there will be cases where the number of decimal places is not maintained. It might be OK if you subsequently use DecimalFormat on the result of that calculation to turn it into a String by rounding, but then why not use DecimalFormat directly in the first place?